# Define keys in temporary table creation

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

How do I define the keys for a temporary table that is being created from a SELECT statement?

I have:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE _temp_unique_parts_trading 
engine=memory AS 
  (SELECT parts_trading.enquiryref, 
          sellingcurrency, 
          jobs.id AS jobID 
   FROM   parts_trading, 
          jobs 
   WHERE  jobs.enquiryref = parts_trading.enquiryref 
   GROUP  BY parts_trading.enquiryref)
```

But where do I define the keys?

Comment: Have you tried just using normal key definitions for tables?

Comment: What do you mean? I have seen tables being created not from a SELECT statement that have had the index columns set, but not once like mine.

Comment: Doesn't matter now, as you've already seen Ajreal's answer, but basically you need to declare the columns fully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

```
CREATE temporary TABLE _temp_unique_parts_trading 
(
  enquiryref varchar(255),
  sellingcurrency varchar(255),
  jobID int(10),
  key(jobId)
)
engine=memory AS 
  (SELECT parts_trading.enquiryref, 
          sellingcurrency, 
          jobs.id AS jobID 
   FROM   parts_trading, 
          jobs 
   WHERE  jobs.enquiryref = parts_trading.enquiryref 
   GROUP  BY parts_trading.enquiryref)
```

Basically append the table schema (index, column data type) right after TABLE_NAME

Comment: Thanks! What is the syntax for specifying a unique index? I assume key(jobId) makes jobId the primary key right?

Comment: KEY(column_name) makes it a simple index non-unique, non-primary; PRIMARY KEY(column_name) or UNIQUE KEY(column_name) makes the column primary or unique.